# Moving results of T-SQL query to a file without using BCP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What I want to do is output some query results to a file. Basically, when I query the table I'm interested in, my results look like this:

```
HTML_ID    HTML_CONTENT
1          <html>...
2          <html>...
3          <html>...
4          <html>...
5          <html>...
6          <html>...
7          <html>...
```

The field `HTML_CONTENT` is of type `ntext` and each record's value is around 500+ characters (that contains HTML content).

I can create a cursor to move each record's content to a temp table or whatever.
But my question is this: instead of temp table, how would I move this without using `BCP`?

`BCP` isn't an option as our `sysadmin` has blocked access to `sys.xp_cmdshell`.

Note: I want to `store each record's HTML content to individual files`

My version of sql is: `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of SSIS to read the table data and output the content of the table rows as files. Export column transformation available within Data Flow Task of SSIS packages might help you do that.

Here is an example, [**The Export Column Transformation**](http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/06/the-export-column-transformation/)

[**MSDN documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139818.aspx) about Export Column transformation.

Answer (score 0):

This answer would have worked until *you added the requirement for Individual Files*.

You can run the SQL from command line and dump the output into a file. The following utilities can be used for this.

- [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)
- [OSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Here is an example with SQLCMD with an inline query

`sqlcmd -S ServerName -E -Q "Select GetDate() CurrentDateAndTime" > output.txt`

You can save the query to a file (QueryString.sql) and use `-i` instead

`sqlcmd -S ServerName -E -i QueryString.sql> output.txt`

**Edit**

Use SSIS

- Create a package
- Create a variable called RecordsToOutput of type Object at the package level
- Use an EXECUTE SQL task and get the dataset back into RecordsToOutput
- Use a For-Each loop to go through the RecordsToOutput dataset

  - In the loop, create a variable for each column in the dataset (give it the same name)
  - Add a Data Flow task
  - Use a OleDB source and use a SQL statement to create one row (with data you already have)
  - use a flat-file destination to write out the row.
  - Use expressions on the flat file connection to change the name of the destination file for each row in the loop.